# Using user login information from a Seam webapp in a Spring webapp

Tags: java, spring, seam, password-encryption

I have a webapp built on the Seam framework and I am currently in the process of replacing this with a new webapp built on Spring. Our users' login information is stored in a database and encrypted using a salted hash. These are current generated in the Seam app with:

```
PasswordHash.instance().generateSaltedHash(plainTextPassword, saltPhrase, "SHA")
```

The problem I'm having is that the new Spring app has to use the same logins and I'm having trouble replicating the password hashing. I currently have this SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    for (AdminUser u : userDAO.getAdminUsers()) {
        System.out.println("Granting access to login: " + u.getLogin()
                + " password: " + u.getPassword());
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(u.getLogin())
                .password(u.getPassword()).roles("USER");
       }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Just add a comment if there's any extra code you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

The way to configure spring security to read users from a given table is via the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, see here the [official docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html).

There is support for defining how to hashing and salting should be done, bellow is how the XML looks like:

```
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="inMemoryDaoImpl"/>
  <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource"/>
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>
```

In Java configuration, in the configure method it's possible to instantiate a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, configure it and pass it to the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` using the API `auth.authenticationProvider(...)`.